# gitlab CI if \ else based on return of "git status"

Tags: git, gitlab-ci-runner

My code now:

```
stages:
  - status
git:
  stage: status
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
  script:
    - sudo salt-ssh "$MINION_NAME" cmd.run "git --git-dir=/srv/salt/.git --work-tree=/srv/salt/salt status"
#    - sudo salt-ssh "$MINION_NAME" cmd.run "git --git-dir=/srv/salt/.git --work-tree=/srv/salt/salt pull"
  only:
    - master
  tags: 
    - Salt-ssh
```

I want the git pull command to run only when git status returns information that the repository has not been changed locally

Also, if git status finds local changes, can I get an error and have the CI page show that the Pipeline Failed

P.S. - I'm doing it this way because I have 15+ servers and I want to see if there are local changes and if there are none, then sync the repository to origin/master

Comment: soo `if sudo .... ; then sudo ...; fi`?

Comment: @KamilCuk How can I make it?

Comment: ? Literally `if sudo salt-ssh "$MINION_NAME" cmd.run "git --git-dir=/srv/salt/.git --work-tree=/srv/salt/salt status" ; then sudo salt-ssh "$MINION_NAME" cmd.run "git --git-dir=/srv/salt/.git --work-tree=/srv/salt/salt pull"; fi`